# Failing HTTP request to Google Sheets API using googleAuthR, httr, and jsonlite

Tags: r, google-sheets-api, httr, r-googlesheets

I'm attempting to request data from a google spreadsheet using the `googleAuthR`.  I need to use this library instead of Jenny Bryan's `googlesheets` because the request is part of a shiny app with multiple user authentication. When the request range does not contain spaces (e.g. `"Sheet1!A:B"` the request succeeds.  However, when the tab name contains spaces (e.g. `"'Sheet 1'!A:B"` or `"\'Sheet 1\'!A:B"`, the request fails and throws this error:

```
Request Status Code: 400
Error : lexical error: invalid char in json text.
                                   <!DOCTYPE html> <html lang=en> 
                 (right here) ------^
```

Mark Edmondson's `googleAuthR` uses `jsonlite` for parsing JSON.  I assume this error is coming from `jsonlite`, but I'm at a loss for how to fix it.  Here is a minimal example to recreate the issue:

```
library(googleAuthR)

# scopes
options("googleAuthR.scopes.selected" = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly")
# client id and secret
options("googleAuthR.client_id" = "XXXX")
options("googleAuthR.client_secret" = "XXXX")

# request
get_data <- function(spreadsheetId, range) {

    l <- googleAuthR::gar_api_generator(
        baseURI = "https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/",
        http_header = 'GET',
        path_args = list(spreadsheets = spreadsheetId,
                         values = range),
        pars_args = list(majorDimension = 'ROWS',
                         valueRenderOption = 'UNFORMATTED_VALUE'),
        data_parse_function = function(x) x)

    req <- l()

    req
}

# authenticate
gar_auth(new_user = TRUE)

# input
spreadsheet_id <- "XXXX"
range <- "'Sheet 1'!A:B"

# get data
df <- get_data(spreadsheet_id, range)
```

How should I format `range` variable for the request to work? Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Use `URLencode()` to percent-encode spaces.

Details:

Using `options(googleAuthR.verbose = 1)` shows that the GET request was of the form:

```
GET /v4/spreadsheets/.../values/'Sheet 1'!A:B?majorDimension=ROWS&valueRenderOption=UNFORMATTED_VALUE HTTP/1.1
```

I had assumed the space would be encoded, but I guess not. In [this](https://github.com/cloudyr/googleCloudStorageR/issues/4) github issue from August 2016, Mark states `URLencode()` was going to be the default for later versions of `googleAuthR`. Not sure if that will still happen, but it's an easy fix in the meantime.

Comment: URLendcoding is in the latest version of googleAuthR, 0.6.2